# Instance object is being overridden automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

So im having a rather unusual issue. Im creating an instance variable and assigning a hash to it. And then im updating that hash and im checking whether the old hash is equal to the new hash after updating. but each time, the old object is some how getting updated and equates to the updated record. Im doing this cause I need to check if the hash has been updated. Here's the code snippet

EDIT: old_json = @old_rules.to_json new_json = @new_rules.to_json and comparing these 2 seems to be working with the correct result. I guess it was working with the same object

```
@old_rules = @mlo.steps[params[:step_id]]["assessment_rules"]
puts "old rules"
puts @old_rules 
#{"48771"=>{"level"=>"Easy", questions"=>"881"}}
@mlo.steps[params[:step_id]]["assessment_rules"].each do |key,value|
  if (rules_data["poolname"] == value["poolname"] && rules_data["resourcetype"] == value["resourcetype"] && rules_data["level"] == value["level"])
    updated_no_of_questions = value["questions"].to_i + rules_data["questions"].to_i 
    value["questions"] = updated_no_of_questions.to_s
    @mlo.save
  end
end

@new_rules = @mlo.steps[params[:step_id]]["assessment_rules"]
puts "updated rules"
puts "new rules"
#{"48771"=>{"level"=>"Easy", questions"=>"885"}}
if (@old_rules == @new_rules)
  #but this condition satisfies as after the update, @old_rules got updated somehow!
  #@old_rules is now #{"48771"=>{"level"=>"Easy", questions"=>"885"}}
  puts "equal"
  @mlo.steps[params[:step_id]]["assessment_rules"].merge!(hash_id.to_s => rules_data)
  @mlo.save
end
```

Comment: Freezing the old object also doesn't seem to be helping. its still getting updated

Comment: The fact that you are creating a new instance variable that points at your hash does not mean that you have a separate copy of the hash object.

Comment: Someone answered below about using `dup`, but you said this doesn't work. (That answer was then deleted, which means most (lower-reputation) SO users cannot see this.) Can you please elaborate on this point? What did you try with `dup`? As far as I can see, you could just do: `@old_rules = @mlo.steps[params[:step_id]]["assessment_rules"].dup`

Comment: Also, you could probably do this with a boolean variable: `rules_changed = false` at the top, then set it to `true` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Or maybe, depending on what `@mlo` is, you could perhaps utilise ActiveRecord's  dynamic method: `@mlo.steps_changed?`. I'm not sure whey you're calling `@mlo.save` multiple times with this approach, why not just call it once at the end? There are several possible ways of approaching this.

Comment: ...And why is `value["questions"]`, which is clearly supposed to be an integer, getting converted to/stored as a string - which just adds mess to the implementation? So many questions...

Comment: @TomLord That's a lot of questions. So firstly, I did the same thing with .dup. It didn't work. So I made it into a json using to_json which is working. Yes I can just do the flag thing too now that you mentioned it which is what i should have tried in the first place.  I tried So mlo.steps is a jsonb field. and there are multiple keys inside it. im checking for a specific deep nested hash. so mlo.steps["xyz"]["xyz"]_changed? didn't work. Number of questions incoming through the params are in string. Saving it as is. So if other params are same I need to combine it by adding the two - to_i

Comment: @TomLord So im calling save cause I need to render particular jsons for particular loops. And I just did it using the flag and its working. Sigh. Thanks

Comment: @Chet The reason I've had to post so many questions, basically, is that your original question is somewhat unclear given the lack of information. What *is* `@mlo`? Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem? Without meaning to sound rude, I don't believe that calling `dup` just "doesn't work". But I don't have any means to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated or implied, your problem is that when you assign `@mlo.steps[params[:step_id]]["assessment_rules"]` to the 2 variables, you're assigning them a *reference* to the same hash; so changes using 1 of the 2 variables will apply to the other.

Assuming there are no complex objects (e.g. other than Hash, Array, String, number, etc.) in `mlo`, a simple and clear way to determine the difference, *and see it visually*, is to call `@mlo.to_yaml` (or `JSON.pretty_generate(@mlo)`) to create a multiline human readable expression of the data before and after, and compare them.

There are tools such as Diffy that can display the differences in a readable way.